# login to a site by completing a form on a different site

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have looked around and haven't yet found an answer to this.

I building a site for a friend who runs a small company, part of the work means that people he employs have to log in daily to a website to get stats and figures. He doesn't own this website, just uses it as a tool.

What he has asked is if I can build a login page. Username, Password and submit button, which will post the details in the text boxes to the login boxes on the external site, submit them and open the page as normal.

So, they just log in through his site,

It logs into the target site and brings back the next page.

Is this possible? Never been asked before.

Comment: Just make the page post its parameters directly to the page to which the original login form posts!

Comment: If the target website protects against cross site forgery this will not work

Comment: Sites that let you login across domains like this usually expose an API for interacting with them. Does the site in question even allow such cross domain scripting? Stated simpler, are you sure you are allowed to do what you are trying to do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Matteo's comment could have been the answer. Just make sure you name your fields according to what the login page expects, make sure your method is what is expected (almost certain POST) and that you use their handler as your action

**Make sure you have permission from the other site to do this!**

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment, I have permission, but they arent that helpful.. I also dont have access to their code.

Comment: If it shows up in a browser, then you have access to their form. If you have their permission, just copy their form directly.

Answer (score 0):

you should `POST` your parameters to the website.

```
<form method="post" action="http://www.example.com">
  <input type="text" name="username" />
  <input type="password" name="password" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="login" />
</form>
```

Comment: That directs to the site but doesn't post to the text boxes or submit.

Comment: it dose, both `POST` and `GET` method send parameters to a page..

Answer (score 0):

Got it working!!

Thanks so much for all your help.

On the advice of **TecBrat** I copied the form, and on the advice of **Mehdi** I changed the form post method from:

```
 <form method=POST enctype="multipart/form-data" >
```

And I changed it too:

```
<script src="js/ajaxsbmt.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<form method="post" action="http://loginpage.com/login/">
```

Thanks for all your help!!